# How to determine when an Image DOM has been removed of its firstchild

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove an image from a DIV element and re-place that with a different image using the code below but it is not working out for me. Nothing is actually happening.

```
 xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp2.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            // DISPLAY CROPPED IMAGE
            var json2_obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp2.responseText);
            var img_path = json2_obj.avatar_path;

            var img_crop = document.createElement('img');
            img_crop.setAttribute('src', img_path);

            // ATTACH IMG TO HTML ELEMENT
            var hook_img = document.getElementById('cropped_image');
            if(hook_img.hasChildNodes()){
            console.log('BEFORE has child: '+ hook_img.hasChildNodes());
            // If hook_img has childnodes, remove all.


            hook_img.removeChild(hook_img.firstChild);
            hook_img.appendChild(img_crop);



            }else{
                console.log('has child: '+ hook_img.hasChildNodes());
                hook_img.appendChild(img_crop);
                 }
```

Using the 'removechild' code only (and not bother with re-appending a replacement child node) I am able to remove the image. However, using both lines of the code results in nothing obervable happening

hook_img has only one child.  I am thinking that i need to add an eventListener for the removal of the firstchild before i can add the replacement child, but i do not know what this event would be.

I have tried using a callback function but that has not worked either:

```
 function clearChildNodes(parentNode, childNode, callback){

            parentNode.removeChild(parentNode.firstChild);
            callback(parentNode, childNode);

        }

 function addChildNode(parentNode, childNode){
            parentNode.appendChild(childNode);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be that, there is a non element child as the first child like a text node so try

```
hook_img.removeChild(hook_img.firstElementChild);//supported in ie 9+
hook_img.appendChild(img_crop);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. it still does not solve it.  if i just use the line first line of my original code, and not bother appending a re-placement child, then i am able to remove the image.  however, using both lines of my code - the original image is still present.

Comment: i've uploaded the ajax call that i make when i press my 'crop button' to display the new cropped image